# Error getting prediction explanation using shap_values when using scikit-learn pipeline?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, nlp, pipeline, shap

I am building an NLP model to predict language type (C/C++/C#/Python...) for a given code.
Now I need to provide an explanation for my model prediction. For example the following user_input is written in Java and the model is predicting that, but I need to show the users why it predicts so.

I am using shap_values to achieve this.
For some reason, the following code results in an error (I have added the error at the bottom).
Please advise how can I get shap_values and plots for my model predictions.

Link to data: https://sharetext.me/bd68ryvzi0

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# Loading Data:
DATA_PATH = r"sample.csv"

data = pd.read_csv(DATA_PATH, dtype='object')
data = data.convert_dtypes()
data = data.dropna()
data = data.drop_duplicates()

# Train/Test split
X, y = data.content, data.language
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, stratify=y)

# Model params to match:
# 1. Variable and module names, words in a string, keywords: [A-Za-z_]\w*\b
# 2. Operators: [!\#\$%\&\*\+:\-\./<=>\?@\\\^_\|\~]+
# 3. Tabs, spaces and Brackets: [ \t\(\),;\{\}\[\]`"']
# with the following regex:
token_pattern = r"""(\b[A-Za-z_]\w*\b|[!\#\$%\&\*\+:\-\./<=>\?@\\\^_\|\~]+|[ \t\(\),;\{\}\[\]`"'])"""


def preprocess(x):
 """ Clean up single-character variable names or ones constituted of a sequence of the same character """
 return pd.Series(x).replace(r'\b([A-Za-z])\1+\b', '', regex=True)\
 .replace(r'\b[A-Za-z]\b', '', regex=True)


# Pipe steps:
# Define a transformer:
transformer = FunctionTransformer(preprocess)
# Perform TF-IDF vectorization with our token pattern:
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern=token_pattern, max_features=3000)
# Create Random Forest Classifier:
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=4)

pipe_RF = Pipeline([
 ('preprocessing', transformer),
 ('vectorizer', vectorizer),
 ('clf', clf)]
)

# Setting best params (after performing GridSearchCV)
best_params = {
 'clf__criterion': 'gini',
 'clf__max_features': 'sqrt',
 'clf__min_samples_split': 3,
 'clf__n_estimators': 300
}

pipe_RF.set_params(**best_params)

# Fitting
pipe_RF.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Evaluation
print(f'Accuracy: {pipe_RF.score(X_test, y_test)}')



user_input = [""" public class Fibonacci {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int n = 10;

System.out.println(fib(n));

}

public static int fib(int n) {

if (n <= 1) {

return n;

}

return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);

}

} """]


import shap

shap.initjs()
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(pipe_RF.named_steps['clf'])
observation = pipe_RF[:-1].transform(user_input).toarray()
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(observation)
```

Load the data and run it to get the following error:

> ExplainerError: Additivity check failed in TreeExplainer! Please
> ensure the data matrix you passed to the explainer is the same shape
> that the model was trained on. If your data shape is correct then
> please report this on GitHub. Consider retrying with the
> feature_perturbation='interventional' option. This check failed
> because for one of the samples the sum of the SHAP values was
> 46609069202029743624438153216.000000, while the model output was 0.004444. If this difference is acceptable you can set check_additivity=False to disable this check.

Comment: Please [reprex]. If you ever tried running the code you post?

Comment: I have run it yes, I have provided the sample data, just load it, copy paste the code and you will see the error. Can you please have a look dear @SergeyBushmanov?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to fix it, posting to help others :)

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

import re
from lime.lime_text import LimeTextExplainer

from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"

# Loading GitHub Repos data containing code and comments from 2.8 million GitHub repositories:
DATA_PATH = r"/Users/stevesolun/Steves_Files/Data/github_repos_data.csv"

data = pd.read_csv(DATA_PATH, dtype='object')
data = data.convert_dtypes()
data = data.dropna()
data = data.drop_duplicates()

# Train/Test split
X, y = data.content, data.language
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, stratify=y)

# Model params to match:
# 1. Variable and module names, words in a string, keywords: [A-Za-z_]\w*\b
# 2. Operators: [!\#\$%\&\*\+:\-\./<=>\?@\\\^_\|\~]+
# 3. Tabs, spaces and Brackets: [ \t\(\),;\{\}\[\]`"']
# with the following regex:
token_pattern = r"""(\b[A-Za-z_]\w*\b|[!\#\$%\&\*\+:\-\./<=>\?@\\\^_\|\~]+|[ \t\(\),;\{\}\[\]`"'])"""


def preprocess(x):
    """ Clean up single-character variable names or ones constituted of a sequence of the same character """
    return pd.Series(x).replace(r'\b([A-Za-z])\1+\b', '', regex=True)\
        .replace(r'\b[A-Za-z]\b', '', regex=True)


# Pipe steps:
# Define a transformer:
transformer = FunctionTransformer(preprocess)
# Perform TF-IDF vectorization with our token pattern:
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern=token_pattern, max_features=1500)
# Create Random Forest Classifier:
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1)

pipe_RF = Pipeline([
     ('preprocessing', transformer),
     ('vectorizer', vectorizer)]
    )

# Setting best params (after performing GridSearchCV)
best_params = {
    'criterion': 'gini',
    'max_features': 'sqrt',
    'min_samples_split': 3,
    'n_estimators': 300
}

clf.set_params(**best_params)
# Here I am preprocessing the data:
X_train = pipe_RF.fit_transform(X_train).toarray()
X_test = pipe_RF.transform(X_test).toarray()

# Fitting the model outside the pipe - feel free to show if possible to do it inside the pipe + fit_transform the train and test sets.
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Evaluation
print(f'Accuracy: {clf.score(X_test, y_test)}')


user_input = """ def fib(n):
                    a,b = 0,1
                    while a < n:
                        print(a, end=' ')
                    a,b = b, a+b
                    print()
                    fib(1000)

   """
clf.predict(pipe_RF.transform(user_input))[0]

prediction = clf.predict(pipe_RF.transform(user_input))[0]
predicted_class_idx = list(clf.classes_).index(prediction)

import shap

shap.initjs()
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(clf, X_train)
observation = pipe_RF.transform(user_input).toarray()
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(observation)


shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value[predicted_class_idx], shap_values[predicted_class_idx], feature_names=vectorizer.get_feature_names_out())
```

[image]